# How to develop tween action in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a flash movie as below.

[image]

I would like to make an action when i click to mc_8 (or any other mc_?) with tween as below.

[image]

Could you suggest a tutorial or method for developing this with AS3 and AS2, please?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

if click to other mc from mc_8 all movie just must move, not scale.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at greensock http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite.
You can add a mouse click handler to your mc_* container, and tween it as:

```
TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {transformAroundPoint:{point:new Point(250,218), scaleX:0.5, scaleY:0.5}, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
```

Answer (score 0):

pre>
you can use greensock framework to implement tween effect.
suppose there is a MovieClip that named mcsBox contains all your mc_*:
`

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import greensock......;

mcsBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  var yourMc:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
  if (yourMc && -1 != yourMc.name.indexOf('mc_'))
  {
     for (var i:int = 1; i < 19; i++)
     {
        var mc_n:MovieClip = mcsBox.getChildByName('mc_'+i) as MovieClip;
        if (mc_n == yourMc) continue;       
          var anyWhereX:number = Math.random() * 600; //  I don't know where you wish to go
          var anyWhereY:number = Math.random() * 600;  // same as above
        TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {transformAroundPoint:{point:new Point(anyWhereX,anyWhereY)}, ease:Bounce.easeOut});          

      }
  }
});
```

`
//------------------
above code may not run correctly you wish. you can optimize it.